# Amend .htaccess path rewrite to include subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have the following .htaccess rewrite rule setup on my site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ index.html?id=$1 [QSA]
```

The rule works in such a way that if I go to the following URL:

http://example.com/dashboard

It won't try and find the dashboard directory that doesn't exist but instead it will keep the URL as is and redirect the user to the root index page. From there I just use javascript to control what view the user will see depending on what path is appended.

The code works exactly as I want it to but i've now had to move my site into a sub-directory on our server. The URL structure is now this:

http://example.com/mysubdir/dashboard

I tried rewriting my rewrite rule to incorporate the directory but have not been successful so far as i'm no .htaccess expert. I tried something along the likes of:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/mysubdir/?$ index.html?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Could anyone tell me how I can amend my rewrite rule to work in my sub-directory?

Comment: Did you move the .htaccess file into the folder to, or is that still at its original location? If the latter, then you must of course refer to the index.html file inside the folder as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close - this should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mysubdir/([^/d]+)/?$ /mysubdir/index.html?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Demo here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=6e574cc6-90a4-54ca-b113-ce72d6eb5203